# withAuth module not exported in next-auth in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, middleware, next-auth

I am trying to add a middleware in the route /admin at next.js, and in the file " _middleware.js" it is like this:

```
    import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";

export default withAuth({
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ req, token }) {
      if (token) return true; // If there is a token, the user is authenticated
    },
  },
});
```

Error:

```
./pages/admin/_middleware.js:1:0
Module not found: Package path ./middleware is not exported from package
```

Path:

```
    pages
    |-------admin
    |--------------_middleware.js
    |--------------index.js
```

Comment: Why do you try to import `withAuth` if you're not using it in your code?

Comment: What version of `next-auth` are you on? `withAuth` was introduced in [v4.2.0](https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/releases/tag/v4.2.0).

Comment: @tromgy I am using, If i Do not import it will result an error then.

Comment: @juliomalves  "next-auth": "^4.1.2", how can I update

Comment: @juliomalves  at the _middleware.js, the token is NULL and I am inside a session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, update your nextAuth dependence.
withAuth was an update at 4.2.0.
https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/releases/tag/v4.2.0
Special thanks to [juliomalves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870780/juliomalves)

Answer (score 0):

use `auth()` if on the `"beta"`/v5+ version of next-auth; `auth()` used in lieu of `withAuth`; refer to:

- https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5
- https://authjs.dev/guides/upgrade-to-v5#authenticating-server-side

a very crude example:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { auth }  from '@/lib/auth';
/*
 * middleware.js
 *
 *   see: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/middleware
 */

export default function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  // log every request
  let datetime = new Date().toString().substring(0, 33);
  console.log(`${datetime} ${request.method} ${request.nextUrl.pathname}`);
  // run auth
  auth();
};
```

and `auth.ts`:

```
import type { NextAuthConfig } from 'next-auth';
import NextAuth from 'next-auth';
/*
 * lib/auth.ts
 */


const providers = [
 [...]
];


export const config = {
  theme: {
    logo: "https://next-auth.js.org/img/logo/logo-sm.png",
  },
  providers: providers,
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ request, auth }) {
      const { pathname } = request.nextUrl
      if (pathname === "/middleware-example") return !!auth
      return true
    },
  },
} satisfies NextAuthConfig;


export const { handlers, auth, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config);
```

note: as of 2024-JAN, one might be on the `"beta"` version if you are avoiding the edge runtime issues on 4.X and Next.js v14+.